# I want to craete two individual elements in select one option element

Tags: javascript

i am using default html select i have option element, i want to insert two elements which i want to make individual and want to click for the second element. here is the sample code that i have implemented. can any one help on this please

```
const data = [
    {vechile:"Maruthi", icon:"Car"},
    {vechile:"Mahendra", icon:"Jeep"},
    {vechile:"benZ", icon:"lorry"},

  ]

 const clickIcon = () => {
    alert("hello");
  };

<select>
        {data.map(item => {
        return <option value="volvo">
<div>
          {item.vechile} </div>
          <div onClick={clickIcon}>{item.icon}</div>
        </option>
        })}
      </select>
```

Comment: What you're trying to do is impossible - you cannot have any other element within an `option`. If you need this, you would need to use a custom dropdown control built in HTML, not the standard `select` control.